# Something wrong when i want to read my cookie - using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am using ASP.NET and VB.NET 2.0.....................................

This is my code i use when i create my Cookie

```
If dlgLogin.RememberMeSet = True Then

        Dim RateCookie As New HttpCookie("LoginInfo")

        RateCookie.Values("Email") = dlgLogin.UserName
        RateCookie.Values("Password") = dlgLogin.Password
        RateCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100)
        Response.Cookies.Add(RateCookie)

    End If
```

And this is my code i use on a Page Load Event to read that Cookie but i cant read it?

```
 If Not Request.Cookies("Email") Is Nothing Then

            Dim RateCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Email")

            Session("myEmailSession") = Server.HtmlEncode(RateCookie.Value)

        End If
```

What am i doing wrong????

Comment: and what's the problem ? what's not working, what error are you getting. "Something wrong" in the question isn't an awful lot to go on

Comment: I am not sure if it is really saving my cookie when i create it....because i cant seem to Read the Cookie..........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you set your cookie as 
`New HttpCookie("LoginInfo")`
, you should read it using

`Request.Cookies("LoginInfo")`, 
not

`Request.Cookies("Email")`.